# Read file from Chrome in Android

Tags: android, vue.js, file-system-access-api

I have a Vue.js web app and custom Android App (I have the source code of both).

I need that the Vue.js web app is able to read a JSON file produced by the custom Android App.

Using the filesystem as the technique of exchange data between the 2 applications I tried the Filesystem Access Api (https://web.dev/file-system-access/) but it seems not supported in Chrome on Android: https://caniuse.com/native-filesystem-api

Do I have other technique of exchange data between an Android app and a Web app without using the internet connection? (no API/FTP). Something like a local storage

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can store the JSON file somewhere on disk of the Android device, you can use a regular [`<input type="file">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) element to upload the file to your Vue app. The File System Access API is not currently supported on Android, as you have noted.